# Conditional Probability and Independence nonsense in a problem

Tags: probability, independence

**The statement:**

Suppose that a patient tests positive for a disease affecting $1$% of the population. For a patient who has the disease, there is a $95$% chance of testing positive, and for a patient who doesn't has the disease, there is a $95$% chance of testing negative. The patient gets a second, independent, test done, and again tests positive. Find the probability that the patient has the disease.

**The problem:**

I can solve this problem, but I'm unable to understand what is wrong with the following:

Let $T_i$ be the event that the patient tests positive in the $i$-th test, and let $D$ be the event that the patient has the disease.

The problem says that $P(T_1, T_2) = P(T_1)P(T_2)$, because the tests are independent.

By law of total probability we know that: 
$$P(T_1, T_2) = P(T_1, T_2\,|\,D)P(D) + T(T_1, T_2\,|\,D^c)P(D^c)$$
Replacing, and assuming conditional independence given $D$, we have:
$$P(T_1, T_2) = 0.95^2*0.01 + 0.05^2*0.99 = 0.0115$$

This is the correct result, but now let's consider that:
$$P(T_1, T_2) = P(T_1)P(T_2)$$

We know that $T_1 = T_i$ for all $i$ because of symmetry, so we have $P(T_1, T_2) = P(T_1)^2$. Again, by law of total probability:
$$P(T_1) = P(T_1\,|\,D)P(D) + P(T_1|D^c)P(D^c)$$
$$P(T_1) = 0.95*0.01 + 0.05*0.99 \approx 0.059$$
So we have:
$$P(T_1, T_2) = P(T_1)^2 \approx 0.059^2 \approx 0.003481$$

The second approach is wrong, but it seems legitimate to me, and I'm unable to find what's wrong.

Thank's for your help, you make self studying easier.

Comment: Why should the tests be independent when not given whether D holds? They should be very highly correlated.

Comment: Events $T_1$ and $T_2$ are not independent events. Unrelated to the error, I think the question asks for $P(D \,|\, T_1, T_2)$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The patient gets a second, *independent*, test done ...

The word "independent" as used in the question does not refer to [statistical independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)). It refers to the second test being done without any direct causal influence from the first test. **The lack of a causal relationship between the two tests does not imply the lack of a correlation between them** (in fact, the results of the two tests are quite positively correlated with each other).

Incidentally, the $^{\text{(fallacious)}}$ idea that [correlation implies causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation) is equivalent (by [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)) to the $^{\text{(also fallacious)}}$idea that a lack of causation implies a lack of correlation.

Perhaps the folks over at the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) can clarify the non-mathematical use of the word "independent" better than I can.

---

We know that for any two events, regardless of independence, the following is true:

$$P(T_1 \cap T_2) = P(T_1) P(T_2 \,|\, T_1)$$

Suppose, for contradiction, that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are statistically independent. By definition,  $$P(T_1 \cap T_2) = P(T_1)P(T_2) $$

In order for the first and second equations above to both be satisfied, it must be the case that $$P(T_2\,|\,T_1)=P(T_2)$$

This is a contradiction. If the first test is positive, the second test clearly must be more likely to also be positive. Therefore, $$P(T_2 \,|\, T_1) \neq P(T_2) \,\,\implies \,\,P(T_1 \cap T_2) \neq P(T_1)P(T_2) \,\, \implies \,\, T_1 \text{ and } T_2 \text{ are not independent }$$

---

The original problem, which asks for the value of $P(D\,|\,T_1, T_2)$, can be solved using [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), and no assumption about the statistical independence between $T_1$ and $T_2$ is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the case that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are independent. They are assumed conditionally independent given $D$ and conditionally independent given $D^c$ but this does not imply (and in fact usually prohibits) that they are unconditionally independent.

Intuitively if $T_1$ is positive, it is more likely they have the disease which makes it more likely for $T_2$ to be positive. So they are not independent.